# How can I correctly align these links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, alignment

The Hello bottom on left isn't correct placed, why?

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 45%;text-align:right">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 45%;text-align:left">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I see four `Hello`s positioned in a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `a` tag automatically added a certain margin after the link automatically, that's whats happening here. Your first anchor tag adds a bit of space that moves the next anchor tag out of place. I've added background color for clarity here, plus a negative margin attribute to the first tag. Hope this helps.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 45%;text-align:right;background-color:bisque;">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%;margin-right:-4px;">Hello</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%;">Hello</a>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 45%;text-align:left;background-color:burlywood;">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens with this solution when the font size of the page changes?

Answer (score 1):

In the left column after the `a` tag and before the `<br/>` tag there was a space. Placing the `br` immediately after the `a` removed that space. So it was the top left and not the bottom left that wasn't aligned.

This only impacted the left column because it had `text-align:right`.

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 45%;text-align:right">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a><br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 45%;text-align:left">
  <a href="lol.html" class="button primary fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="lol.html" class="button fit" style="width:50%">Hello</a>
</div>
```